# IIS 7.5 - Initial page load works fine, but refreshing page causes 401.1 Unauthorized

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I have just completed moving a site from IIS 6 to IIS 7.5, but simply copying the ASP files and setting up the new site on IIS 7.5 with its own application pool. I didn't try to export / import the site - just an out of the box configuration.

I am facing an issue however, the pages are using Windows Authentication and what I am finding is a user can successfully navigate to index.asp and it correctly authenticates them as the user. However if they refresh the page they will get an "Enter your credentials" box. Even if they put the right credentials in they will get a "401.1 Unauthorized" message.

However, if the user waited for 30 seconds and refreshes the page it authenticates correctly.

For some reason if users refresh the same page in 30 seconds or less the Windows Authentication fails.

Just wondered if anyone had ever seen anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a checklist I've been building from my move from IIS 6 to 7.5:

(1) Do not name site folders with .com, .net, etc at the end.

(2) Create NEW user account:
- [app pool user identity] is user: app_pool_blahblahblah, pw: xxxxxx

(3) In Server Manager, right click "Web Server (IIS)" and choose "Add Role Services". Add IIS 6 Management Compatibility.

(4) In Server Manager under features add SMTP server.
Install IIS6 Resource Kit so you can 
Use Metabase Explorer.
Grant the [app pool user identity] user read access to the /Local Machine/SmtpSvc/ and /Local Machine/SmtpSvc/1/ nodes in the IIS Metabas

(5) In Application Pool, advanced settings:
- set .Net Framework version to "v2.0" <-- fixed issue with default asp doc not working!
- set "Enable 32-bit applications" to TRUE.
- set managed pipeline mode to "Classic". <-- this may not  be necessary.
- under Process Model, change Identity to "[app pool user identity]" account we created.
- be sure "load user profile" is set to FALSE.
- be sure "maximum worker processes" is "1".

(6) Mail: In IIS 6 Management Console:
http://intellitect.com/configuring-windows-smtp-server-on-windows-2008-for-relay/
- Under SMTP Virtual Server Properties:
    -- "Access" Tab --> Relay: add IPs of this box, including 127.0.0.1
    -- "Delivery" Tab --> Advanced: for "fully qualified domain name" put name of box
    -- "Delivery" Tab --> Advanced: for "smart host" put "dedrelay.secureserver.net"
    -- "Delivery" Tab --> Outbound connections: Make sure limits are set to 100.
    -- "Security" Tab --> add "[app pool user identity]" and IIS_IUSRS

(7) In IIS 7.5 under web site:
- Under ASP:
    -- ONLY IF PROBLEM: set enable buffering to "false"
    -- under limits change max req entity and buffering limit to 1024000000
    -- set script language to "vbscript"
    -- set "send errors to browser" to true
- Authentication --> edit "Anonymous Authentication" and set to app pool identity.
- ONLY IF PROBLEM: under error pages: under 404 set to "/home.asp" and "execute URL"
- ONLY IF PROBLEM: edit c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config: change  to "Allow"
- under Management (at bottom) go into "Configuration Editor".
    -- In the dropdown go to System.web --> http runtime and change maxRequestLength to 1024000000
    -- In the dropdown go to System.webserver/security/requestFiltering --> chg allowDoubleEscaping=true

(8) 
Set "Modify" Permissions for [app pool user identity] for the following folders: 
- your web site
- windows\temp
- inetpub\temp
- inetpub\mailroot
- ONLY IF PROBLEM: windows\serviceprofiles\networkservice\AppData\Local\Temp?

AND Set Permissions in registry:
- ONLY IF PROBLEM: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines?

FOR THESE USER ACCOUNTS:
- IIS_IUSRS
- [app pool user identity]
- NETWORK SERVICE

(9) Install and Use Process Monitor to find permissions issues - filter

(10) Make sure SSL v2 is not being used:
Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
In Registry Editor, locate the following registry key/folder:
HKey_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders
\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0
Right-click on the SSL 2.0 folder and select New and then click Key. Name the new folder Server.
Inside the Server folder, click the Edit menu, select New, and click DWORD (32-bit) Value.
Enter Enabled as the name and hit Enter.
Ensure that it shows 0x00000000 (0) under the Data column (it should by default). If it doesn't, right-click and select Modify and enter 0 as the Value data.
Restart the computer.
Verify that no SSL 2.0 ciphers are available at ServerSniff.net or the Public SSL Server Database

(11) SSL issue where Safari tells client that it needs a certificate. 
- Go into IIS settings for the SSL-protected site. 
- Click on "SSL Settings"
- Choose "ignore".